# Rails - loading before redirecting Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When the user click on the link

```
http://localhost:3000/initial_link
```

it should redirect to another url,

```
http://google.com/redirected_link
```

Here while redirecting, Loading image need to be shown.

I tried as ,

```
def click
  render 'loading' and return
  redirect_to 'http://google.com/redirection_link'
end
```

But above wont work.

Note: *Also, redirection should not happen in Js.*

Answer (score 0):

make your link_to as

```
<%= link_to_remote t('click'), :url => { } ,:loading => "$('loader').show();", :loaded => "$('loader').hide();" %> 
<%= image_tag("loader.gif",:id => "loader", :style => "display: none;") %>
```

then in controller,

```
render(:update) do |page|
  page.redirect_to 'http://google.com/redirection_link'
end
```

Comment: Here, link_to wont work, Because the' initial link' will be directly given to client and client will make his user to click the link from different framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
def initial_action
  unless request.xhr?
    response.headers["Location"] = "http://google.com/redirected_link"
    render template: "your_controller/initial_action", status: 301
  end
end
```

I think this works but cannot understand why you need this.